# Custom object updated from customer community are not firing email notification?

Tags: community, process-builder, napili

We have customer service community. Through community the user updates the status of one custom object XYZ to 'Completed'. 
We have process builder in system which fires the email alert on the update of the custom object XYZ and status equal to 'Completed'.
The email alert is not getting fired when status changed through community user, wherein if i manually change the status of the custom object in internal salesforce the email alert seems to fire.

Comment: Do your community users have permissions in their profiles to access email? If not, that would be the source of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, please check on "Email Alert" the Setting "From Email Address" on your Email Alert.

Didn't work with "Current Users's email address" change it to an "Organization-Wide Addresses"!!

Second I guess the "Additional Emails" does not work too.

hope this helps you!
J.